# Should FORALL place outside of for loop?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm new to PL/SQL.
I decided to use the following SQL to insert thousands of record to a table. However, is it correct to place the FORALL statement outside for loop?
Is it better to move the FORALL statement inside for loop block? Thank you.

```
DECLARE

   CURSOR books_cur
   IS
    SELECT book_id, book_type
    FROM books
    WHERE book_category = 'PROGRAMMING';

   TYPE book_ids_t IS TABLE OF 
    books.book_id%TYPE;

   l_book_ids   book_ids_t := book_ids_t();

BEGIN
   FOR i IN books_cur LOOP
    IF(i.book_type = 'PLSQL') THEN
        l_book_ids.EXTENDS;
        l_book_ids(l_book_ids.LAST) := i.book_id;
    END IF;
   END LOOP;

   FORALL i IN l_book_ids.FIRST..l_book_ids.LAST
    INSERT INTO table_a (book_id) VALUES l_book_ids(i);
END;
```

Comment: btw there is no requirement for brackets around `if` conditions. They won't break anything, but they are clutter and the compiler will ignore them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Is it better to move the FORALL statement inside for loop block"

No. FORALL is a set operation. You need to execute it once per unit of work, not once per row.

> " to insert thousands of record to a table"

Please remember that collections are maintained in **session memory**. This means you need to be more conscious of memory management when you're working with very large numbers of records.

So you may want to work in batches, something like this:

```
BEGIN
   FOR i IN books_cur LOOP
        IF(i.book_type = 'PLSQL') THEN
            l_book_ids.EXTENDS;
            l_book_ids(l_book_ids.LAST) := i.book_id;
        END IF;
        if l_book_ids.count() = 1000 -- say
        then 
          FORALL i IN l_book_ids.FIRST..l_book_ids.LAST
              INSERT INTO table_a (book_id) VALUES l_book_ids(i);
          l_book_ids.delete();
        end if; 
     END LOOP;
     FORALL i IN l_book_ids.FIRST..l_book_ids.LAST
        INSERT INTO table_a (book_id) VALUES l_book_ids(i);    
END;
```

This version of the code inserts records in batches of 1000, with a supplementary FORALL statement to catch the last batch which is likely to be less than 1000 records.

However, the most efficient way of implementing your example remains

```
INSERT INTO table_a (book_id) 
SELECT book_id
FROM books
WHERE book_category = 'PROGRAMMING'
and  book_type = 'PLSQL';
```

Comment: You point out what I exactly worried about is the memory usage! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

No, your FORALL is in the correct place. Of course, your example program doesn't need this at all, it could be written as:

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO table_a (book_id)
SELECT book_id
    FROM books
    WHERE book_category = 'PROGRAMMING'
      AND book_type = 'PLSQL';
END;
```

But I realise you are interested in learning the FORALL concept rather than writing the simplest code!

Answer (score 0):

In your example, FORALL requires the collection `l_book_ids` as input. 
Inside the FOR loop, the collection is not yet fully created, so you cannot use FORALL on it.
FORALL is one statement, as APC mentioned, you cannot break it into multiple steps - as a matter of fact this is its advantage - it does the work fast, in one shot.